# UCI - what should be the value of movestogo

Tags: uci

Playing a bullet game(1 min) against UCI engine, I would send these command from GUI

```
 uci
 setoption name Hash value 256
 isready
 ucinewgame
 position startpos e2e4
 go wtime 60000 btime 60000 movestogo xx
```

what should be the value of xx?

Documentation says

> movestogo – Number of moves to the next time control. If this is not set, but wtime or btime are, then it is sudden death.

But before the game completes how do I know how many moves would be played in the game?

Comment: "Number of moves to the next time control.", not "Number of moves to the end of the game"

Answer (score 1):

In a bullet game, you don't send movestogo. You only do this in case of a game where there is an increment after let's say move 40 where an additional 15 minutes might be added to the clock. Even then, the engine would still need to know, how much time is added after xx moves have gone by to make proper use of the time at its disposal.

Comment: thx! but how to set time for bullet game. if I set wtime,btime without movestogo it won't work

Comment: position startpos moves e2e4 is the correct syntax

Comment: If I send only `startpos moves e2e4` without `wtime ,btime`   stockfish always loses on time.